# Options for untraceable IP for a web form action?

Tags: forms, google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda

I have a web site with privacy-enabled domain name, and a web contact form. The web page is served via AWS CloudFront. e.g. http://www.my-site.com.

The question is how to serve the form action script. My form has a GET action to http://form.my-site.com.

The script behind the form is very simple, and could be written in any language. It makes a simple call to my own server. Just a few lines of code.

What are your ideas for hosting in a way that the IP for the form action is a floating, common IP that could be shared by totally unrelated projects. i.e., so the form IP doesn't reveal or uniquely identify the owner. It should also be super reliable.

Comment: Unless `my-site.com` (a working web site) is *your site*, you should not use someone else's domain name in this way.  See http://example.com.

Comment: good point. I will not next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your application [post the form to CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/10/15/amazon-cloudfront-now-supports-put-post-and-other-http-methods/) wouldn't that hide the backend server IP from the client?

Also, if your server were simply using a public IP assigned by AWS, wouldn't that be fairly anonymous?

Comment: Mark, Thanks. I thought about simply using CloudFront. I know it's very good for content, but will it proxy a form request instantly?  I prefer to avoid EC2 (or any fixed IP).

Comment: I'm starting to get a weird vibe from this question. I can't think of any reason you would need to hide behind a rotating IP address unless you were doing something illegal.

Comment: Don't let your imagination go wild. It's nothing nefarious. It would just be for privacy. No one hiding from the government would use paid AWS accounts, which are trivial to subpoena. Anyway, I have solved my question using CloudFront (your idea), or AWS Lambda + AWS API Gateway. I'm still curious about other ideas if anyone else reads this thread. As I don't consider these methods particularly creative.